# Drupal Migrate - Link fields from an XML Source

Tags: 7, navigation, migrations

I am using the Migrate (v7.x-2.2) module to migrate records from an XML source into Drupal 7.9.

I've also installed the popular link field module (v7.x-dev).

So far, in my migration class, all built-in fields work well during the migration, but I have not figured out how to migrate link fields from my XML source with their title.

I have two XML source fields (xpaths):

```
/record/organization/name  <-- I want to migrate this into the link title
/record/organization/url   <-- I want to migrate this into the link url
```

I am able to get the URL to import using this line in my Migration file (had to use link v7.x-dev module, not 7.x-1.0):

```
   $this->addFieldMapping('field_organization', 'organization_url')->xpath('/record/organization/url');
```

...but I have no idea how to inject the `/record/organization/name` into the title argument:

```
   $this->addFieldMapping('field_organization', 'organization_url')->xpath('/record/organization/url')->arguments(array('title' => [WHAT GOES HERE?]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the solution is to not use arguments, but instead, fix up the record using the prepare() method:

In the constructor:

```
//IMPORTANT - DO this source mapping without a destination mapping (NULL)
$this->addFieldMapping(NULL, 'organization_title')->xpath('/record/organization/title');

$this->addFieldMapping('field_organization', 'organization_url')->xpath('/record/organization/url');
```

Then, create a method named prepare():

```
function prepare($node, $rec) {
      $node->field_organization[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['title'] = $rec->organization_title;
}
```

As of today (Nov 30, 2011), you must have the 7.x-dev version of the link module installed, not the "stable" 1.0 version, in order for link fields to work at all!

Whew!

Answer (score 1):

I found a working MigrateLinkFieldHandler here:

http://drupal.org/node/1004066

I uploaded the latest 'patch' from there, which is basicly a single class definition (*), to a file called 'link.inc' in my migratemodule, and added a reference to that file in my module.info there. Cleared caches et voila:

```
 $arguments = MigrateLinkFieldHandler::arguments(
      array('source_field' => 'url_title')
 );
 $this->addFieldMapping('field_link', 'url')
        ->arguments($arguments);
```

(*) ofcourse, since its a patch, i had to remove all the ++++ and superfluous lines to get a nice working php class )